# Whats the best way to include static information in my app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am currently working on my first small desktop menubar app (macOS, Swift 3). It needs to access

a) A list of words (Think word dictionary, 1k-5k words, per supported language)

b) A list of structured data (Think simple structs, ~500)

I am currently pondering, whether to build these in code - maybe a factory class per language. Or include them in my app as json and parse at runtime. Or maybe build an SQLite file and read that during runtime, although that approach would be harder to diff in source control ...

As I am new to the platform I was wondering whether there might be a better way that I am not aware of, or maybe performance considerations that render one of the mentioned approaches useless.

As usual, thanks in advance folks !

Comment: I would use the json approach. Create a single factory class to access data with a language parameter (like `getWordsForLanguage()`), and load the json lazily (e.g load once on first access, keep in memory after).

Comment: Should this not have been an answer instead of a comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Your listed solutions can be used for this task. However I think for such kind of tasks the best solution is to use CoreData, where you can store a list of words as well as structured data, also make relations between them if you need it

Comment: I would not recommend Core Data for this task. Core Data is designed for heavy stuff. It will not give you noticeable performance benefits for such a simple task, only a much more complex design, harder to maintain and modify.